# How to check one file is saved or not?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How can I check one file(`IFile`) is saved or not?There is one method in `IOpenable` interface for checking saved or not.But  in this case how can I get `IOpenable` from `IFile`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if the file is open in any editor and has unsaved changes in there?

Comment: I just want to check the file is saved or unsaved.Either it is open in case of unsaved or not open in case of saved

Comment: Where do you get the `IFile` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming everyone is well-behaved, you can try using `FileBuffers.getTextFileBufferManager().getFileBuffer(...)` and then check the obtained buffer(s) with `IFileBuffer.isDirty()`.

Answer (score 0):

`IResource` that is the parent of `IFile` and `IFolder` and has the method `exist()` which you can use to check whether the resource exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

just loosely, you could create a file object to use to save something like this but that is dependent exactly how you derive the java.io.File object itself in the Eclipse framework.
so just figuratively coded...

```
class MySaveFile extends java.io.File implements org.eclipse.jdt.core.IOpenable,org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile{

MySaveFile(String savefilename){
super(savefilename);
}//end constructor


} //end class
```

**URL: here's an actual example for eclipse
http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t65832.html**